# Perl: to calculate date difference and average day

Tags: perl, date

These are my data;

```
 Ticket Submitted_date      Ticket closed_date
 2017-05-11 12:47:08.2      2017-05-26 07:00:16.0
 2017-05-11 13:23:10.96     2017-05-27 22:01:02.0
 2017-05-11 13:23:02.483    2017-05-24 08:10:20.0
 2017-05-11 13:28:35.247    2017-05-24 08:12:33.0
```

Codes as below,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $qstr = "select id as 'id', status as 'status', $subject.title as 'title', $subject.component as 'component', $subject.submitted_date as 'submitted_date', $subject.closed_date as 'closed_date' where ($subject.status = 'complete' OR $subject.status = 'rejected')";
my $results = &search($api, $tenant, $subject, $qstr); 

foreach my $singleRow (@$results) {
        my $title =$singleRow->{'title'};
        my $component = $singleRow->{'component'};
        my $sub_date = $singleRow->{'submitted_date'};
        my $closed_date = $singleRow->{'closed_date'};

       $sub_date =~ /^(.{4})-(.{2})-(.{2})T(.{2}):(.{2}):(.{2})\.(.{3})/;
```

No idea on how to calculate the average days of above data.
Need assistance... New to Perl...

Comment: What do you mean by "_average days_"?

Comment: 1. Extract the dates from the variable/line (using `split` or regex or both)  2. Find a module for Date/Time  that you like.  An easy choice is [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.43/lib/DateTime.pm) but there sure are others. Most of them have some facility for what you need. 3. Put the date/time in the format that the module wants

Comment: Your date-time is in a very standard format and many modules understand it, so you don't need to parse it (once you get it from the line of data that you show)

Comment: @zdim: The _“average days”_ are the ones that are neither boring nor exciting.

Comment: @PerlDuck Oh, right.  Silly me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };    
use Syntax::Construct qw{ /r }; # /r in 5.014

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $results = [[ '2017-05-11 12:47:08.2',   '2017-05-26 07:00:16.0' ],
               [ '2017-05-11 13:23:10.96',  '2017-05-27 22:01:02.0' ],
               [ '2017-05-11 13:23:02.483', '2017-05-24 08:10:20.0' ],
               [ '2017-05-11 13:28:35.247', '2017-05-24 08:12:33.0' ]];

my $sum = 0;
for my $single_row (@$results) {
    my ($from, $to) = map 'Time::Piece'->strptime(
                           s/\.[0-9]+$//r, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
                      ),
                      @$single_row;
    my $delta = $to - $from;
    $sum += $delta;
}
my $average = $sum / @$results;
say 'AVERAGE: ', $average / ONE_DAY, ' days.';
```

[Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) doesn't support sub-second precision, so the result might be a few microseconds off.